# How to prevent bottle from handling signals

Tags: python, signals, bottle

I am building an application using the Bottle web-framework.

I would like to catch signals USR1 and USR2 to do some work aside from the bottle server. Mainly I want to be able to reload configuration without shutting down the web server because I want some objects to live on.

I tried to handle the signals (USR1 and USR2) on my own using :

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, my_handler)
```

The problem is that, upon receiving a sigUSR1, the bottle web server crashes with the following trace :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "giomanager.py", line 46, in <module>
    run( giomanager, port=60200 )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 2389, in run
    server.run(app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 2087, in run
    srv.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 225, in serve_forever
    r, w, e = select.select([self], [], [], poll_interval)
select.error: (4, 'Interrupted system call')
```

Do you have an idea why is this happening ? Is it possible to prevent bottle from receiving those signals ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post your code, so I'm guessing that it might boil down to something like this:

```
import signal
from bottle import route, run

def my_handler(*args):
    print 'in signal handler', args

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, my_handler)

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!\n"

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Which, incidentally, works for me--it prints "in signal handler."

**But**: what I really wanted to suggest is that you consider another mechanism altogether for refreshing your data.  I've had much success with a separate refresh thread that repeatedly sleeps for some duration, then wakes up and polls a certain file (or url) to see if there's new data.

There are several reasons why this might be better than using signals, not least of which is that it'll be a pain (or impossible) to signal each process if you ever run multi-process.  Besides, you weren't planning on running the Bottle development server in production, were you?  (It's [not recommended](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html#server-options) for anything but the smallest of apps.)  Given that, once you run your Bottle app within another webserver, signal handling becomes tricky.

Comment: Thank you for you response.
I was not planning on using bottle on production but I've seen somewhere that it can be embed within other web server.
I will follow your suggestion and handle my event using files and pyinotify.

Comment: Cool, happy it helped.  And thanks for mentioning pyinotify; I hadn't heard of it before--it might have saved me a few hours of coding something similar myself.